# In acute $\Delta ABC$, $O$ is circumcentre. $M,N$ on $AB,AC$, s.t. $O$ lies on $MN$. $D,E,F$ are midpoints of $MN,BN,CM$. Prove O,D,E,F are concyclic.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

> In acute $\Delta ABC$, $O$ is the circumcentre. $M,N$ lie on $AB,AC$ respectively, s.t. $O$ lies on $MN$. $D,E,F$ are midpoints of $MN,BN,CM$ respectively. Prove that $O,D,E,F$ are concyclic.

I was able to prove that $DE||AB$ and $DF||AC$, and that $\angle EDF = \angle BAC$. Thus it remains to prove that $\angle EOF = \angle BAC$. However, I can't seem to get a relation between $\angle EOF$ and other angles.

[image]

Moreover, on Geogebra, I found that $\Delta AMN \sim \Delta OFE$, but I can't prove it.

[This was given to me as an exercise by my teacher.]

Answer (score 2):

Let $B',C'$ be points on the circumcircle so that $BB',CC'$ are diameters.  Then $OE\parallel B'N$, $OF\parallel C'M$.  Now $B'N, C'M$ meets at some point $X$ that is on the circumcircle:

> *Proof*: The intersections $C'X\cap AB=M, BB'\cap CC'=O, AC'\cap B'X=N$ are collinear so the six points $A,B,C,B',C',X$ are conconic by [Braikenridge–Maclaurin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braikenridge%E2%80%93Maclaurin_theorem).  But $A,B,C,B',C'$ are all on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, so $X$ is too.  QED

Now we angle chase:
\begin{align*}
\angle BAC&=\angle BAX+\angle XAC\\
&=\angle BB'X+\angle XC'C\\
&=\angle BOE+\angle COF
\end{align*}
and $\angle BOC=2\angle BAC$, so
\begin{align*}
\angle EOF&=\angle BOC-\angle BOE-\angle COF\\
&=\angle BAC
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Comment: Do we use the Braikenridge–Maclaurin theorem in the hexagon $C'XB'BAC$?

Comment: Also, is there any way to prove this without the theorem?

Comment: I suppose we can compute it in coordinates.  It isn't too bad to show $ODEF$ cyclic from Ptolemy's.